# Use one line javascript if in html snippet

Tags: javascript, html, quotes

This fieldHTML variable is used for creating dynamic field when user press 'add field' button. I'm saving these dynamic fields values in localStorage. After refreshing the page I want to check if this input has saved value and if yes, display this input. Problem is that with this one line if statement which is defined in value attribute my input don't showing even it has value. What's wrong with the line where I defining input value? I believe it's the problem with quotes, because when I try to debug this one line if in console.log I'm getting text value empty. I'm not getting any error in console.

```
var fieldHTML = '<div> \
<input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name" \
            value="'+(localStorage.getItem(array['name'][i])) ? localStorage.getItem(array['name'][i]) : 'empty' +'" /></div>';
```

Comment: Can you [edit] to explain more clearly what problem you're seeing, as in what you expected to happen, and what is happening instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `\` Multiline support is limited to browsers supporting ES5 only.
2. `'empty' +'"` Unexpected string concatenation of literals.
3. Put the **if** to a frame with brackets `((localStorage.getItem(array['name'][i])) ? localStorage.getItem(array['name'][i]) : 'empty')`

Modified script:

```
var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name" value="'+ ((localStorage.getItem(array['name'][i])) ? localStorage.getItem(array['name'][i]) : 'empty') + '" /></div>';
```